# Share stock with Opencart

Tags: stock

Hi i was wondering if it is possible to have interaction between opencart and magento stores. We currently are working on a magento store for our website and our supplier is going over to opencart. Our supplier only uses a in stock and out of stock status and we would like to have their status showing on our website as well. I am just curious if such a thing is possible since this will safe our support staff time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to dig into the API functionality of Magento and/or OpenCart. What you want to do is call the Magento API from OpenCart to send the stock information from OpenCart to Magento.

The other way around is also an option, but in that case it won't be possible to change the status in your webshop on the fly.

More information about the Magento 1 Stock API: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalogInventory/Inventory.html

Hope this will help you out.